# Prevent Dropbox from creating Start Menu folder

Tags: windows, windows-10, dropbox

Every time I start Windows, Dropbox creates a "Dropbox" folder in my Start menu, which I find very annoying. Is there a way to turn this behavior off? Note that I don't want to disable Dropbox from starting, just that it keeps creating these folders/shortcuts.

**Edit** to clarify: The folder keeps reappearing after I delete it

`C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Dropbox`

Comment: Go into Dropbox settings and make sure Microsoft Office is unchecked (under Start Dropbox on System Startup).  Dropbox does not create a Start Menu item on my system.

Comment: I see the "Microsoft Office add-in" (show Dropbox as save location) and it is (and always was) disabled. Strange.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try deleting the folder? If so, it shouldn't appear again. (you didn't specify this is your que)

Also removing a start menu folder will  make it disappear from the start menu too, I don't think you want that happening, do you?  (although there are other ways of starting Dropbox).

Comment: Yes, I have tried deleting the folder **many** times. I have a copy of the _Dropbox_ link in another subfolder. I would like to keep my root directory clean and free of noise that I don't use.